# Cartesian Tensor Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors, index-notation

I have a problem in proving a problem, which is easy to do in basic multivariable calculus but I couldn't do it in tensor notation. Please help

$$\nabla.(r^n \vec{r})=(n+3)r^n$$
Here $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is the magnitude of the position vector $\vec{r}=xi+yj+zk$.

I tried representing(i don't know if this is the right way either) $r$ like this $(x_ix_i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\vec{r}=x_j$ and $\nabla = {\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}}$
Therefore, my representation is as follows:
$$\nabla.(r^n \vec{r})=(n+3)r^n$$
$$LHS={\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}}((x_ix_i)^{\frac{n}{2}}x_j)$$

And I run into problems which I couldn't resolve like these terms appeared,

How do I turn this $x_mx_m(x_ix_i)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ into this  $(x_ix_i)^{\frac{n}{2}}$

So, I dont't know how to resolve these kind of problems. Please help. If my interpretation are wrong please tell me the right one.

Comment: Hint: First you need to realize that $i$ is a dummy variable. Then you can see that the quantity that you write as $(x_{i}x_{i})^{n/2}$ could (should?) be written as $(x_{i_{1}}x_{i_{1}})^{1/2}(x_{i_{2}}x_{i_{2}})^{1/2}...(x_{i_{n}}x_{i_{n}})^{1/2}$ (no summation over $n$ of course).

Comment: @Peter Both $i$ and $m$ is a dummy variable, right? BTW, is my representation for $r^n$ correct?

Comment: Yes to both your questions. This also means that in your (slightly confusing, but efficient) notation we have $x_{m}x_{m}(x_{i}x_{i})^{n/2-1} = (x_{i}x_{i})^{n/2}$.

Comment: @Peter I still do not understand how to make the logical step from turning this $x_mx_m(x_ix_i)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ into this  $(x_ix_i)^{\frac{n}{2}}$, also I am constrained by the fact that I cannot have more than two repeated index

Comment: @Peter my another confusion is such that $x_ix_i$ is $x_1x_1+x_2x_2+x_3x_3$ then shouldn't $(x_ix_i)^n$ be $(x_1x_1)^n+(x_2x_2)^n+(x_3x_3)^n$

Comment: We should do the summation first, $(x_{i}x_{i})^{n} := (\Sigma_{i} x_{i}x_{i})^{n} = (x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2})^{n}$. You can verify the equation I wrote down earlier directly: $x_{m}x_{m}(x_{i}x_{i})^{n/2-1} = (\sum_{m}x_{m} x_{m})(\sum_{i} x_{i} x_{i})^{n/2-1} = (\sum_{i} x_{i} x_{i})(\sum_{i} x_{i} x_{i})^{n/2-1} = (\sum_{i} x_{i} x_{i})^{n/2}$.

Comment: But @Peter your summation term contains 4 repeated indices which I specifically tried to avoid.

Comment: The point is that when you are using the Einstein summation convention then you should *avoid* repeated indices, because it is ambiguous. However, when you are more explicit (by writing $\Sigma$ and using appropriate brackets) then there is no chance for confusion.

Comment: So, basically it is impossible to arrive at the solution without being explicit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63850/discussion-between-peter-and-jyotishraj-thoudam).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, while what you wrote is perfectly fine, it might be easier (pedagogically speaking) to only sum upper and lower indices, and make spatial variables contravariant (i.e. upper indices). Then you have to use the Kronecker delta, so that:
$$ x_ix_i \rightarrow \delta_{ij}x^ix^j $$
converts between our notations.

For your last question about $x_mx_m(x_ix_i)^{n/2 - 1}$, I'd say:
$$ (\delta_{ij}x^ix^j)(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2 - 1} = (\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2 - 1} = (\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} = r^n $$
since they are indeed dummy indices.

And then, with great explicitness (warning, this may not be stomachable to all viewers), I'd prove your identity via:
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot(r^n\vec{r}) 
&= \partial_j [(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2}x^j] \\
&= x^j\partial_j (\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} + (\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2}(\partial_jx^j) \\
&= x^j\partial_j (\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\
&= x^j\frac{n}{2}(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2-1}[\delta_{k\ell}(x^k\delta^\ell_j + x^\ell\delta^k_j)] + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\ 
&= x^j\frac{n}{2}(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2-1}[2x^a\delta_{ja}] + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\ 
&= {n}(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2-1}[\delta_{ja}x^ax^j] + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\ 
&= {n}(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2-1}[\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell] + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\ 
&= {n}(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} + 3(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\
&= ({n} + 3)(\delta_{k\ell}x^kx^\ell)^{n/2} \\ 
&= (n+3)r^n
\end{align}